# Clustered vs. GMM-based standard errors: which ones to use in asset pricing?

Tags: asset-pricing, capm, fama-french, estimation, covariance-matrix

Consider estimating an asset pricing model such as the CAPM or a multifactor model using monthly data. [Petersen (2009)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/22/1/435/1585940) section "Asset pricing application" suggests use of standard errors clustered by time, as this addresses the problem of cross-sectional correlation. (Meanwhile, serial correlation is not much of an issue.) [Petersen (2009)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/22/1/435/1585940) discusses how time-clustered standard errors fare against alternative approaches such as Fama-MacBeth (works fine) and several other. However, he does not seem to consider GMM estimation that is discussed extensively in Cochrane ["Asset Pricing"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691121376/asset-pricing) (2005) Part II, e.g. Chapter 11.

On the other hand, Cochrane does mention clustered standard errors and Petersen's paper in his video lecture on the topic; see [here](https://youtu.be/lkFon5Jhw-A?t=294) and again [here](https://youtu.be/lkFon5Jhw-A?t=321). However, he does not compare between clustered standard errors and GMM-based ones either.

So how do clustered standard errors and GMM-based standard errors compare? (If needed, we may consider (1) clustering by time and (2) assuming zero autocorrelation in GMM for concreteness.) Is one a special case of the other? Which ones makes more sense (given that 13 years have passed since Petersen's paper, I guess there should be some consensus on the matter)?

*Due to lack of answers, this has been reposted on [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/604830).*

**Update** (now posted as a [separate question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75745))
After some thinking, I am not sure if I can even formulate a statistically adequate panel regression model. Take the case of the CAPM written in terms of excess returns (thus the asterisks):
$$
R_{i,t}^*=\beta_i\mathbb{E}(R_{m,t}^*)+\varepsilon_{i,t}.
$$
We can generalize it to allow for nonzero Jensen's $\alpha$
$$
R_{i,t}^*=\alpha_i+\beta_i\mathbb{E}(R_{m,t}^*)+\varepsilon_{i,t}
$$
(and later test $H_0\colon \alpha_1=\dots=\alpha_N=0$), but we have the problem of $\mathbb{E}(R_{m,t}^*)$ not being observable. Just replacing $\mathbb{E}(R_{m,t}^*)$ with $R_{m,t}^*$ would introduce measurement error and bias the estimate of $\beta_i$. Adding time fixed effects would not help  with the problem. To see that, express $R_{m,t}^*$ as $R_{m,t}^*=\mathbb{E}(R_{m,t}^*)+\varepsilon_{m,t}$, yielding
$$
R_{i,t}^*=\alpha_i+\beta_iR_{m,t}^*+\beta_i\varepsilon_{m,t}^*+\varepsilon_{i,t}
$$
where we see that the time fixed effect is convoluted with $\beta_i$. So how does one even start working out standard errors clustered by time if the model itself is inadequate? Or did I miss something?

**References**

- Cochrane, J. (2005). [*Asset Pricing: Revised Edition*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691121376/asset-pricing). Princeton University Press.
- Petersen, Mitchell (2009). ["Estimating Standard Errors in Finance Panel Data Sets: Comparing Approaches"](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/22/1/435/1585940). *Review of Financial Studies 22 (1)*: 435–480.
  (A freely accessible working paper version can be found [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=661481).)

Comment: I don’t have access to the book now but the OLS type methods described in the article should be special cases of GMM methods.

Comment: Optimal clustering depends on application. For cross-sectional regressions one would expect cross-sectional correlation of errors to be a bigger issue though you can also correct for both.